# Не работает layout_weight при LinearLayout vertical

Tags: android

Имеется корневой тег `LinearLayout` с вертикальной ориентацией, в котором 3 дочерних таких же `LinearLayout`. Если в каждом из дочерних поставить `layout_weight="1"`, `layout_height="match_parent"`, а в корневом `weightSum="3"`, то, как и ожидалось, дочерние занимают каждый 1/3 высоты. Однако если поменять в корневом вес скажем на 4, а в среднем из дочерних поставить `layout_weight="2"`, то второй и третий дочерний уползают куда-то вниз за пределы экрана, хотя я ожидал, что средний займет половину общей высоты, а верхний и нижний - по одной четвертой

Comment: не испольтзуйте `layout_height="match_parent"` вместе с `weight`. Это приведет к непредсказуемым последствиям. Полностью предсказать полседствия можно только при `layout_height="0dp"`

Comment: поставьте вложенным контейнерам высоту layout_height="0dp". Если все вложенные элементы имеют параметр веса, то в корневом указывать weightSum не обязательно - он будет вычислен из вложенных

Comment: да, при 0dp все заработало как надо, спасибо ))

Answer (score 1):

Ваши ожидания верны. Попробуйте убрать weightSum, ибо он в данном случае не обязателен. Также проставьте высоту в `0dp`

Comment: `WeightSum` полностью не бесполезен и позволяет задать пропорции, когда не все виджеты в контейнере имеют вес. Например, если корневой контейнер имеет `weightSum = 2`, а вложенный `layout_weight = 1`, то вложенный будет занимать 50% от корневого, что полезно, когда нужно одному виджету определенное соотношение, а остальным, что осталось по их высоте `wrap_content`

Comment: @pavlofff, хм... не знал этого) Исправил на "необязателен в данном случае")